# Jquery Ajax Click Event Not Responsive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, events

I have been trying to link a click event to a php function using ajax, using buttons in php. however when i click on the buttons absolutely nothing happens. Im not sure why.
This is my php code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#aeps').click(function () {
        var printpayslips = $(this).val();
        $_ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../print.php';
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                printslip: printpayslips
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    })
    $('#ps').click(function () {
        var paysum = $(this).val();
        $_ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'print.php';
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                printsum: paysum
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    }) $('#create').click(function () {
        var cr = $(this).val();
        $_ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'print.php';
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                create: cr
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: He's newbie in stackoverflow, give him a chance @serakfalcon

Comment: @Alaeddine fair, after I posted I went to format the code myself but I guess you were already editing

Answer (score 2):

It helps to run the code using Chrome, since the developer console will tell you where your code dies.

Some things to note:

unless you wrote a specific ajax function called `$_ajax`, jQuery's ajax function is `$.ajax`. Also, every `url:` line you wrote ends with a semicolon where it should end with a comma.